# Fill NaNs in dataframe with different numbers

Tags: python, pandas, replace, nan

I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [np.NaN, 1, 2], 'Col2': [7, 9, np.NaN], 'Col3': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 5]})
```

How can I replace each NaN in `df` with a random unique number which is not existing in `df`, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [8, 1, 2], 'Col2': [7, 9, 11], 'Col3': [30, 33, 5]})
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to mask with a df the same size of random numbers:

```
import random
total_size = df.shape[0]*df.shape[1]
rands = [x for x in random.sample(range(total_size*10), total_size*2) if x not in df.values][:total_size]
rands_mat = np.array(rands).reshape((df.shape))
df.mask(pd.isnull(df), rands_mat)
```

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 7 | 23 |
| 1 | 1 | 9 | 19 |
| 2 | 2 | 71 | 5 |

Comment: it works. thank you very much :)